# Play Framework Json Validation

Tags: json, playframework

I'm trying to parse a json structure, validate it and use the validated result.

```
 def createEntry = Action(parse.tolerantJson) { request =>
  request.body.validate[MyJson].map { myJson =>
    // do something with the MyJson object
  }.recoverTotal { err => BAD_REQUEST }
```

The MyJson object looks like this:

```
case class MyJson(
  complexType: ComplexType,
  strs: Seq[String],
  maps: Map[String, ComplexType]
)

case class ComplexType(
  str1: String,
  bool1: Boolean,
  cxType2: ComplexType2,
  maps: Map[String, String]
)

case class ComplexType2(str: String, strs: Seq[String])
```

Would the validate method automatically try to box the JSON string into the object type? os Should I write an additional body parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the appropriate `Format` or `Reads` objects in scope for `MyJson`, yes, `response.body.validate` will automatically parse the JSON string into a `MyJson` instance, only entering the `recoverTotal` block if the JSON validation fails (i.e., the JSON in the request cannot be parsed into a `MyJson`, even if it is a valid JSON string).

Comment: What would be the Format or Reads objects for MyJson? Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: There's great documentation available here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonCombinators

Comment: @user3102968 You should read the documentation on Play's JSON library as it covers all of that.